# Can't connect to NodeJS Express Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I can't connect to my Express server. I'm trying to use Axios to connect from my front end but it never reaches the endpoint. Also when I attempt to connect directly from the browser it just spins. When I start the server, I do see the console log message from the listen function, so it appears to be running. But the Axios.post never gets tot he /login route.

Here is my index.js on the Server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    databaseName: 'ncaa'
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const userName = req.body.userName;
    const password = req.body.password;

    db.query("SELECT * from user where username = ? and password = ?", [userName, password], (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            res.send({err: err});
        }
        
        if (result){
            res.send(result);
        }
        else {
            res.send({message: "Username or password is incorrect"});
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('App running on 3001');
});
```

Here is my app.js on the client

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const authenticateLogin = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
      userName: userName,
      password: password 
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
    
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event) => { setUserName(event.target.value) }}/>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" onChange={(event) => { setPassword(event.target.value) }}/>
        <button onClick = {authenticateLogin}>Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors()); // cors is a function, you have to call that function
app.use(express.json());
```